# Windows: Delete specific Active Directory accounts via Powershell Script (remote)

Tags: powershell

folks,

my Active Directory accounts with admin privileges all start with the same characters: "ad" followed by a dot and the name of the admin. Example: "ad.tim".

I would like to have admin accounts (every account beginning with "ad.") automatically deleted (profiles and user data) by the Windows clients and would like to distribute a Powershell script to my clients (better ideas are welcome).

I'm not very familiar with Powershell nor Scripting, but I allready figured out (thanks, Google) how to list all Accounts:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | select LocalPath
```

Now I'd have to filter (-like ad.*) and delete, but I'm not sure how or where to install it. It would be great if someone could give me some information so that I can better understand it and reach my goal!

Comment: You can select matching accounts using a [WQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) filter.  For example: `Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE LocalPath LIKE '%ad.%'"`.  Note that it is recommended (where possible - PS3.0+) to use the 'CIM' cmdlets instead of the 'WMI' ones.

Comment: Thanks for showing me a direction. The output looks good, but I can't pipe it for deletion:

     Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE LocalPath LIKE '%adm.%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalPath | Remove-WmiObject -verbose -WhatIf

I'm getting the flollowing error: 

    Object -ExpandProperty LocalPath | Remove-WmiObject -verbose -WhatIf

I'm not sure, but I think its not usuable via Pipe. Any ideas? PS: I can't format my response?!

Comment: You are mixing up the (recommended) CIM cmdlets I used with the (deprecated) WMI ones you used, as well as passing the wrong type to `Remove-WmiObject`.  That isn't going to work.  Check out the 'Programatically' section here: [Different methods of removing user profiles](http://virot.eu/different-methods-of-removing-user-profiles/).  I didn't test it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: OMG, I feel dumb now. Thank you, now I got it. My one-liner seem to work fine: Remove-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE LocalPath LIKE '%ad.%'" Thanks again for directions.