# Delete User Profile in Windows using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am creating a script which should delete profiles which haven't been used in the last 180 days in Windows systems.

Following is my code.

```
$profiles = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where {
    (!$_.Special) -and
    ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1))
}
$count = $profiles | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
if ($count -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "No Profiles found for Deletion"
    exit
}
Write-Output "Number of profiles : $count"
$profiledeleted = @()
$profileerror = @()
foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
    $profile | Remove-WmiObject
    if ($?) {
        $profiledeleted += $profile.Localpath 
        continue
    } else {
        $profileerror += $profile.Localpath
    }
}
if ($profiledeleted.Length -gt 0) {
    Write-Output "Localpath of removed profiles"
    $profiledeleted
}
if ($profileerror.Length -gt 0) {
    Write-Output "Error While removing below profiles"
    $profileerror
}
```

The code should run with the system account but I am getting the following error.

```
Remove-WmiObject :
At C:\Users\Admin\GRT-2687_deleteunuseduserprofiles.ps1:22 char:32
+     $profile | Remove-WmiObject <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

Edit : It is deleting all the data except the folder C:\Users\Username.

Comment: Check out this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290063/windows-delete-specific-active-directory-accounts-via-powershell-script-remote

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386318/1630171).